# Unable to create Angular 5 project using angular-cli

Tags: angularjs, linux, angular-cli, npm-install, angular5

Even after re-installation can't make ng use angular-cli 1.6

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe-perm

/usr/bin/ng -> /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.1.10 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN @schematics/schematics@0.0.10 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.40 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+@angular/cli@1.6.0

updated 1 package in 22.197s
```

ng still shows older version

```
$ ng -v

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3

node: 8.9.2

os: linux x64

@angular/common: 2.4.10

@angular/compiler: 2.4.10

@angular/core: 2.4.10

@angular/forms: 2.4.10

@angular/http: 2.4.10

@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10

@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10

@angular/router: 3.4.10

@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have installed a old version of the `angular cli` globaly.
Try to uninstall it with this commands:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli 
npm cache clean
```

Here the [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update) to the update story on github anglur-cli.